# Limit of Geometric Sequence when $r\approx 1$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

We know that the Geometric sequence $r^n$ converges for $|r|<1$ and converges to 1 for $r=1$.

Suppose that $r\approx 1$ say $r=0.99$. We know that the sequence will converge to $0$ but my question is can we increase the speed of convergence? I am facing such issues while coding and I want to increase the speed of convergence. As in coding, I can't take $n\rightarrow \infty$ I want some value which works for me. For, $r\in [0,0.8]$ or any such interval I am able to work with $n=100$ but not when $r\approx 0.99$

Comment: What do you mean by "some value that works for me?"  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can write the partial sums of a geometric series and its limit in closed (algebraic) form. You never need to loop to calculate them. So I'm not sure what "speed of convergence" means.

Comment: i think in other since you are looking for the best upper bound for $|r^n|$ such that $r \in [0,1)$

Comment: Agree with others that it's unclear what you want.  It would be great if you could add more details, but just in case this is what you're looking for, there is no $n$ such $r^n$ will be small ( ie. less than some fixed $\epsilon$ ) for all $r<1$.

Comment: I want some $n$ such that $r^n$ converges to zero fast. Even if not to zero then converges to something like $1e^{-8}$. I am writing a code where I want to find the limit of the Geometric sequence. As limit is not a pre defined function in C++, I am using an approximation. So, for $r$ not close to 1, I am able to work with $n=100$ but I am not able to work when $r$ is near 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a set precision $0<\epsilon<1$, for given $0< r <1$ you can find $n$ such as $r^n<\epsilon$. Here is how: $\large{\ln r^n< \ln \epsilon}$ means than $\large{n >\frac{\ln \epsilon}{\ln r}}$ (sign changes because we divide by a negative number).